# Javascript error with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've created a simple static HTML page using the Google Maps API v3. This works fine in some browsers (IE v8 on Windows XP) but I'm having trouble getting it to load in the latest versions of Safari on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and Windows XP. I get these errors when I turn the Safari developer console on:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new google.maps.Size(150,50)')
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new google.maps.LatLng(-30.2965590,153.1152650)')
```

I've put a copy of the file online at:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34923164/Errors_GoogleMaps.htm

Here's the html contents as well:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Google Maps Sample</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = null;
function initialize() {
var myOptions = {
zoom: 13,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-30.2965590,153.1152650),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
myOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
infowindow.close();
});
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-30.2965590,153.1152650);
var icon = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png';
var marker = createMarker(point,'Location: 33 Harbour Drive Coffs Harbour', icon)
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-30.2864430,153.1360230);
var icon = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
var marker = createMarker(point,'Person: Fred Flinstone (108 Park Beach Road Coffs Harbour)')
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-30.2941737,153.1156785);
var icon = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
var marker = createMarker(point,'Person: Barney Rubble (108 Grafton St Coffs Harbour)')
}
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{
size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
});
function createMarker(latlng, html, icon) {
var contentString = html;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latlng,
icon: icon,
map: map,
zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infowindow.setContent(contentString);
infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i've tried your code posted on dropbox and didn't see any error using Safari 5.1 (Lion) and Chrome 12.0.742 maybe you have something wrong in cache or your network has some problem and it didn't download javascript code from google correctly

my 2 cents

Comment: This is what is wierd. Sometimes if I continually empty the cache in Safari and quite/launch a few times it will work. But generally the first time I load the page from a local file it won't!

Comment: mumble it's strange my only idea is some sort of network error, when you get the error try to see in the network panel the content of google javascript maybe something goes wrong when you load that code